# Ehcache vs BigMemoryMax for Distributed caching

Tags: caching, ehcache, distributed, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I want to try Ehcache in distributed form. Can someone suggest me if EHcache (Not the BigMemoryMax) works in distributed mode.

I am looking for only open source product. I am not looking to buy a Bigmemory Max or Terracota server, which will give me a off heap access, which i dont need as of now.
If so, please provide the version, url and some guide/examples to implement distributed Ehcache.
Thanks...

Comment: is `ehcache` a strong requirement? Have you tried Hazelcast? It's open source implementation of distributed Java Collections like Maps, Lists, Sets. http://hazelcast.org

Comment: It is not a strong requirement...we are doing a poc among different caching f/w and ehcache is one of them. Does hazelcast provide admin console/visor like ignite to check the cluster performance.

Comment: it does. It calls management center and it's a webapp https://hazelcast.com/products/management-center/

Answer (score 0):

[Ehcache website](http://ehcache.org) is your best starting point:

- Ehcache 2.10.x has open source clustering support with Terracotta 4.3.x
- Ehcache 3.1.x has open source clustering support with Terracotta 5

Comment: Thanks Louis...I was able to install Terracotta4.3 with ehcache....One followup...Is there admin console or management console in TC 4.3 open source....where I can manage my server cluster

Comment: No, that is not an OSS feature. But there are ReST APIs that can be used to interrogate the cluster. http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/tms/tms-rest-api - references an older version but the API is valid, although you have to connect to the cluster directly and will lack the enterprise specific options.